# How to determine database provider at the IEntityTypeConfiguration, because I support multiple databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

Can anybody tell me how I can get the current database provider at line 9?
So it can generated the migration correctly for the MySQL migrations.
How do I do this the clean way.

```
1 internal class GroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
2 {
3   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Group> builder)
4   {
5      builder.ToTable(nameof(Group));
6      builder.HasKey("Id");
7      builder.Property(u => u.Id)
8         .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
9         .HasDefaultValueSql((database.IsMySql()) ? "uuid()" : "newsequentialid()");
...
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1, and my webapp supports multiple database providers.
For now MySQL (Pomelo) and SQL Server.
I need it to generate the migration the correct way. So I have a MySQL and SQL Server migrations.

But I don't want to update the MySQL generated migration manually.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @Matt No, I didn't it the way I wanted. I added multiple DbContexts, so one for MSSQL and one for MySQL. Then in the Startup I made the switch so it will know which DbContext to use based on a appsetting. Then I create the migration for both DbContexts.
So this 'HasDefaultValueSql' line I have removed.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to pass the `DatabaseFacade` to your configuration class:

```csharp
internal class GroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
   private readonly DatabaseFacade _database;

   public GroupConfiguration(DatabaseFacade database)
   {
        _database = database;
   }

   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Group> builder)
   {
      builder.ToTable(nameof(Group));
      builder.HasKey("Id");
      builder.Property(u => u.Id)
         .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
         .HasDefaultValueSql((_database.IsMySql()) ? "uuid()" : newsequentialid()");
...
```

And then pass the `Database` property in `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GroupConfiguration(Database));
    // ...
}
```

Keep in mind that the configuration class can no longer be created by `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly()`, so you have to add the configuration with `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration()`.